# PHP some highest values from array

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, max

Using this snippet:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
echo max($array);
```

i get:

```
10
```

But how to get the three highest values from this array, so the output will be:

```
10,9,8
```

in this order. Anybody know  how to customize the max-function?

Greetings!

Comment: lol u should have asked how to get 4 highest values :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
  rsort($array);
  echo $array[0]," ", $array[1], " ", $array[2];
```